# When trying to save music to home on Ubuntu, it says I would only have 20GB space even though my partition has 270GB, what's wrong?

Tags: partitioning, home-directory

I'm a bit stuck here, and I'm new to Ubuntu so please forgive me if this is a stupid question :D.

Lately, I tried to save 60GB of Music to my home folder's music folder in Ubuntu but it said there would only be 10GB free space out of 20GB. But I installed Ubuntu to a partition of 270GB of which 240GB are still free. Apart from that, I have a `D partition` with 100GB and a `C partition`, with Windows on it, of 70GB and no other partition. When I looked in terminal, it said, there would also be something like a partition (but I don't know if it is) called `loop`, of 29GB. Considering that Ubuntu takes about 8GB, this could be where my home folder is but I don't know if this is right, and I don't know what to do in order to get more space (the 240GB).

Can someone please help me?

```
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xb33d55e5

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    52430847    26214400   1c  Hidden W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sda2   *    52430848   201422969    74496061    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       201422977   976773119   387675071+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       201423040   411970859   105273910    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       411970928   976773119   282401096    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Comment: Can you please type `sudo fdisk -l` on the terminal and give the output here?

Comment: There is no Linux partition. Was this a Wubi installation?

Comment: I think so... my brother did it for me while I watched so I don't know exactly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you install with WUBI, you give a selection for the size of the partition you want, usually up to 30GB. In this case, that was selected, and a 30GB file was created, in which everything Ubuntu uses, goes into. This file is not dynamic, as it will only hold up to 30GB, and it would be 30GB, even if you have only written 4GB to it. The best solution is to install Ubuntu from the live CD on its own partition with the amount of space you need.

If you want to still use Wubi, you can use `/host` to access your Windows C:\ drive from within Ubutu. If you configure your music downloader  to stick music there, or create a symlink with:

```
ln -s /host/Users/[yourWindowsUsername]/Music ~/WindowsMusic
```

and you can put your music into `WindowsMusic` in your home folder.

Answer (score 0):

May be you have to check your partitions again, to make sure that you have installed Ubuntu in correct partition. You can do this by `sudo parted -l`